# How to calculate square root in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, math

I need to calculate an euclidean distance in a sqlite database.

Does anyone know how to calculate square roots in sqlite beside writing and loading a dynamic library for math functions?

I am close to resorting to the fast inverse square root algorithm in here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root though it might to turn into more fun than I need right now.

And as a side note, it'd be great to figure out how to do power (which is the generalized question, and is cleaner coding than multiplying a number by itself).

Thanks,

Simone

Comment: How accurate does it have to be?

Comment: Use [extension function](http://sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25). [Here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Math-Functions-td38826.html) is a thread about it.

Comment: When comparing euclidean distances you can square both sides and not take a square root - also power might look like cleaner code but is often slower as done by logs although there are other ways for integral powers

Comment: I think power isn't supported by SQLite either.

Comment: Power is indeed not supported by native SQLite.

Comment: @Mark: thanks - smart answer. Totally avoiding the problem is often better than solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [2021-03-12 (3.35.0)](https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_35_0)
>
> **Added built-in SQL math functions()**. (Requires the -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS compile-time option.)

**[Built-In Mathematical SQL Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html)**

> **sqrt(X)**     Return the square root of X. NULL is returned if X is negative.

Answer (score 6):

**Warning:** this answer is dependent on the coding language. In my case **C#**.

User defined SQLite functions was for me a pain to implement. Finally, after a long time of searching I was able to implement it in my C# code. Main function looks like this:

```
[SQLiteFunction(Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar, Name = "Sqrt")]
class Sqrt : SQLiteFunction
{
    public override object Invoke(object[] args)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(args[0].ToString()));
    }
}
```

Registration of custom function:

```
SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(Sqrt));
```

And using in select:

```
SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand("select sqrt(10.42)", connection);
```

You can download full example here: http://db.tt/qzeNXwso

Or, if you want only view code (or get through all parts of my code), I paste below full working example code for calculate square root in SQLite database, because is very hard to find any working code for this. To create and run this example do this 6 steps:

1. Create new project (my name is Sqrt)
2. Include SQLite reference to your project: 
   *Solution Explorer -> References (right click: Add reference) -> Assemblies - Extensions - System.Data.SQLite (check) -> OK*
3. Open *App.config* and replace to this (without this step you maybe get *Mixed mode assembly* error):

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`
     `<configuration>`
         `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">`
             `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>`
         `</startup>`
     `</configuration>`
4. Replace your *Form1.Designer.cs* with this code:

   ```
   namespace Sqrt
   {
    partial class Form1
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       if (disposing && (components != null))
       {
           components.Dispose();
       }
       base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
       this.txb_Input = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
       this.txb_Output = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
       this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
       this.btn_Calcualte = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
       this.SuspendLayout();
       // 
       // txb_Input
       // 
       this.txb_Input.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(131, 12);
       this.txb_Input.Name = "txb_Input";
       this.txb_Input.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(201, 20);
       this.txb_Input.TabIndex = 0;
       // 
       // txb_Output
       // 
       this.txb_Output.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
       this.txb_Output.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(131, 38);
       this.txb_Output.Name = "txb_Output";
       this.txb_Output.ReadOnly = true;
       this.txb_Output.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(201, 20);
       this.txb_Output.TabIndex = 0;
       // 
       // label1
       // 
       this.label1.AutoSize = true;
       this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 15);
       this.label1.Name = "label1";
       this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(31, 13);
       this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
       this.label1.Text = "Input";
       // 
       // label2
       // 
       this.label2.AutoSize = true;
       this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 41);
       this.label2.Name = "label2";
       this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 13);
       this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
       this.label2.Text = "Output";
       // 
       // btn_Calcualte
       // 
       this.btn_Calcualte.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(257, 64);
       this.btn_Calcualte.Name = "btn_Calcualte";
       this.btn_Calcualte.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
       this.btn_Calcualte.TabIndex = 2;
       this.btn_Calcualte.Text = "Calculate";
       this.btn_Calcualte.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
       // 
       // Form1
       // 
       this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
       this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
       this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(344, 98);
       this.Controls.Add(this.btn_Calcualte);
       this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
       this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
       this.Controls.Add(this.txb_Output);
       this.Controls.Add(this.txb_Input);
       this.Name = "Form1";
       this.Text = "Root square example";
       this.ResumeLayout(false);
       this.PerformLayout();
    }
    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txb_Input;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txb_Output;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btn_Calcualte;
    }
   }
   ```
5. Open Form1.cs (code) and replace code with this:
       using System;
       using System.Data.SQLite;
       using System.Windows.Forms;

   ```
   namespace Sqrt
   {
       // definition of custom sqlite function
       [SQLiteFunction(Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar, Name = "Sqrt")]
       class Sqrt : SQLiteFunction
       {
           public override object Invoke(object[] args)
           {
               return Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(args[0].ToString())); // return result of math sqrt function
           }
       }

       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
           public Form1()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
               this.btn_Calcualte.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_Calcualte_Click);
           }

           private void btn_Calcualte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               if (txb_Input.Text.Length == 0)
                   return;
               try { SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test.s3db"); }
               catch { }
               SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.s3db");
               SQLiteFunction.RegisterFunction(typeof(Sqrt)); // register custom function
               con.Open();
               SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand("select sqrt(" + txb_Input.Text.Replace(',', '.') + ")", con); // select result
               string res = com.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
               txb_Output.Text = res;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Run, try and enjoy.

Comment: Is this part `Double.Parse(args[0].ToString())` there to handle values that are the wrong type?

Answer (score 5):

This is an approximation of sqrt for numbers under 10000.   It can be extended for arbitrary numbers, and can be extended to arbitrary precision as needed.   This kind of tabular interpolation is what happens in most fast implementations anyway:

```
case when weight >= 1 and weight<=10 then 1+0.240253073*(weight-1) 
     when weight>=10 and weight<=100 then 3.16227766+0.075974693*(weight-10) 
     when weight>=100 and weight<=1000 then 10+0.024025307*(weight-100)      
     else 31.6227766+0.007597469 *(weight-1000) end
```

And there's the curious fact that each factor you use in such a power-of-10 square root interpolation table is 0.316227766 times the previous one - so you can make this work for an arbitrarily large number, or even stuff a table full of these values to make it work for any number.   (Could that lead to some compression here?)

Or this cute one for log10 of integers, using the length function (an interpolation table might work better here, but I like that log10 and length() are similar, and that this works for any integer - no interpolation needed.

```
 ((length(x)+length(x*2)+length(x*3)
  +length(x*4)+length(x*5))/5.0)-1.0
```

A better math head than I can probably come up with better and denser approximations.   Considering that most sqrt functions in c use approximations anyway - this is a pretty good solution.

*This is the only native way of doing it.*

Comment: If `weight` is 9 then the result of the expressins is 2.922, if `weight` is 16 result is 3.618  I was expecting something closer to 3 and 4. Can you explain your formula and the level of error?

Comment: 1. pop open an excel sheet, 2. compute square roots, and 3. do a linear interpolation for a set of arbitrary weights.   the forumula above is *horribly approximate*.    you can do way better

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know - you can't do that using only core functions.

Here is the list of native functions [Core functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) and a list of aggregate functions [Aggregate functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

To solve your problem, you can write your own UDF (user defined function) as illustrated [HERE](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteScalarFunction.html)

Answer (score 1):

Only if math functions are not available... and really only in desperation because this isn't gonna be fast...

```
-- bisect to find the square root to any tolerance desired
with 
 input(n) as (select 500), --input
 sqrt(lo, hi, guess, n, i) as (
  select 1, n, n/2, n, 0 from input
  union all
  select case when guess*guess < n then guess else lo end,
         case when guess*guess < n then hi else guess end,
         case when guess*guess < n then (hi+guess)/2.0 else (lo+guess)/2.0 end,
         n ,
         i +1 from sqrt
         where abs(guess*guess - n) > 0.0001), -- tolerance
 sqrt_out(x, n) as (select guess, n from sqrt order by sqrt.i desc limit 1)
 select * from sqrt_out
```

Comment: This is fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the distance only for comparison in your select you don`t need sqrt. You can compare with the powered distance as well...

```
poweredDistance = (x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1)
```

...and sqrt the distance later in your code outside of sqlite.

But if you need to select gps points of a ceatain area, here is a dart code I made with the help of OpenAI (GPT-4):

```
/// <pre>
///         [N++lat]
/// [W--lon]        [E++lon]
///         [S--lat]
///
/// Latitude zero is at Equator
/// Longitude zero is at GB London, Gateway to London Campus, University of the West of Scotland (UWS),
/// </pre>
class GpsArea {
    final GPS north;
    final GPS east;
    final GPS south;
    final GPS west;

    /// South border
    double get latMin => south.lat;

    /// North border
    double get latMax => north.lat;

    /// West border
    double get lonMin => west.lon;

    /// East border
    double get lonMax => east.lon;

    bool isInArea({required double lat, required double lon}) {
        return (lat >= latMin && lat <= latMax && lon >= lonMin && lon <= lonMax);
    }

    GpsArea(
            {required this.north,
            required this.east,
            required this.south,
            required this.west});

    /// based on ChatGPT-4 response
    static GpsArea calculateArea(
            {required double latitude,
            required double longitude,
            required int distance}) {
        // Constants for Earths radius in meters
        const earthRadius = 6371000.0;

        // Convert the start position to radians
        final startLatitudeRad = radians(latitude);
        final startLongitudeRad = radians(longitude);

        // Calculate distances in radians
        final latDistanceRad = distance / earthRadius;
        final lonDistanceRad = distance / (earthRadius * cos(startLatitudeRad));

        // Calculate new latitudes and longitudes
        final northernLatitude = asin(sin(startLatitudeRad) * cos(latDistanceRad) +
                cos(startLatitudeRad) * sin(latDistanceRad) * cos(0));
        final southernLatitude = asin(sin(startLatitudeRad) * cos(latDistanceRad) +
                cos(startLatitudeRad) * sin(latDistanceRad) * cos(180));

        final easternLongitude = startLongitudeRad +
                atan2(
                        sin(lonDistanceRad) * cos(startLatitudeRad),
                        cos(latDistanceRad) -
                                sin(startLatitudeRad) * sin(northernLatitude));
        final westernLongitude = startLongitudeRad -
                atan2(
                        sin(lonDistanceRad) * cos(startLatitudeRad),
                        cos(latDistanceRad) -
                                sin(startLatitudeRad) * sin(southernLatitude));

        // Convert the new latitudes and longitudes to degrees
        final northernLatitudeDeg = degrees(northernLatitude);
        final easternLongitudeDeg = degrees(easternLongitude);
        final southernLatitudeDeg = degrees(southernLatitude);
        final westernLongitudeDeg = degrees(westernLongitude);

        // Create the surrounding GPS points
        final north = GPS(northernLatitudeDeg, longitude);
        final east = GPS(latitude, easternLongitudeDeg);
        final south = GPS(southernLatitudeDeg, longitude);
        final west = GPS(latitude, westernLongitudeDeg);

        return GpsArea(north: north, east: east, south: south, west: west);

        /*
        void test() {
            final area =
                    calculateArea(latitude: 50, longitude: 30, distance: 1000.0);

            print("Northern Point: ${area.north.lat}, ${area.north.lon}");
            print("Eastern Point: ${area.east.lat}, ${area.east.lon}");
            print("Southern Point: ${area.south.lat}, ${area.south.lon}");
            print("Western Point: ${area.west.lat}, ${area.west.lon}");
        }

                            Northern Point: 50.008993216059196, 30
                            Eastern Point: 50, 30.021770141923543
                            Southern Point: 49.99100678394081, 30
                            Western Point: 50, 29.978238001159266
        */
    }
}
```

This calculates a rectangle area. If you need circles, you can select a rectangle first and cut off the edges with a distance calculation method later like this one:

```
/// found here: https://github.com/baseflow/flutter-geolocator/tree/main/geolocator
/// if I remember right

/// Calculates the distance between the supplied coordinates in meters.
///
/// The distance between the coordinates is calculated using the Haversine
/// formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). The
/// supplied coordinates [startLatitude], [startLongitude], [endLatitude] and
/// [endLongitude] should be supplied in degrees.
static double distanceBetween(
    double startLatitude,
    double startLongitude,
    double endLatitude,
    double endLongitude,
) {
    var earthRadius = 6378137.0;
    var dLat = toRadians(endLatitude - startLatitude);
    var dLon = toRadians(endLongitude - startLongitude);

    var a = pow(sin(dLat / 2), 2) +
            pow(sin(dLon / 2), 2) *
                    cos(toRadians(startLatitude)) *
                    cos(toRadians(endLatitude));
    var c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));

    return earthRadius * c;
}

static double toRadians(double degree) {
    return degree * pi / 180;
}
```